# Understanding Constraint Matrix in Example Problem

Tags: matrices, inequality, linear-transformations, linear-programming, affine-geometry

I have found a pretty nice description of the [polyhedra model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model) in [this paper](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~pouchet/doc/pouchet-phdthesis.pdf). They are describing the math behind iterating through for-loops in a program (in last figure below), which forms a **polyhedron of affine inequalities**. Earlier they give definitions of affine functions and polyhedra.

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of the matrices below (first figure), which I assume is somehow related to the polyhedron of affine inequalities. I was wondering if one could explain the elements of the matrices below.

The following passage describes the matrix / first figure:

> Iteration domains capture the dynamic instances of all statements — all possible values of surrounding
>   loop iterators — through a set of affine inequalities. For example, statement R in Figure 2.1 is executed
>   for every value of the pair of surrounding loop counters, called the iteration vector: the iteration vector
>   of statement $R$ is $\vec{x_R} = (i, j)$. Hence, the iteration domain of R is defined by its enclosing loop bounds:
>
> $$D_R = \{i, j \mid 1 \leq i \leq lg−1 \land 1 \leq j \leq wt−1\}$$
>
> which **forms a polyhedron (a space bounded by inequalities, a.k.a. hyperplanes or faces)**. To model
>   iteration domains whose size are known only symbolically at compile-time, we resort to **parametric
>   polyhedra**. Program constants which are unknown at compile-time are named global parameters and the
>   parameters vector is noted $\vec{n}$. For instance for the Ring-Roberts example lg and wt are global parameters
>   and $D_R$ is a parametric form of $\vec{n} = (lg\ wt)$.
>
> Each **integral point inside this polyhedron corresponds to exactly one execution of statement $R$**, and
>   **its coordinates in $D_R$ matches the values of the loop iterators at the execution of this instance**. This model
>   let the compiler manipulate statement execution and iteration ordering at the most precise level.
>   In the remainder of this thesis, we use **matrix form in homogeneous coordinates to express polyhedra**.
>   For instance, for the iteration domain of $R$ is written:
>
> [image]

[image]